# sfdx `--plan` import fails "INVALID_FIELD Cannot reference a foreign key field XXX__r"

Tags: salesforcedx

Would anyone know how to leverage the `sfdx force:data:tree:export ... --plan`  functionality to export following data model? I believe I somehow need to export from each parent separately and ensure the `-plan.json` file reference fields match?

Feel free to suggest ForceCLI or some other approach that would work better in this situation.

[image: two parents to common child export]

I get the following sample error when attempting to import:

```
INVALID_FIELD  Cannot reference a foreign key field cms__Content_Layout__r.
=== cms__Content_Template_Relationship__cRef86 [1]
STATUSCODE     MESSAGE                                                       FIELDS
─────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────  ──────
INVALID_FIELD  Cannot reference a foreign key field cms__Content_Layout__r.
```

With this SOQL query used, which does return data for both parents:

```
Select c.cms__hasChildren__c

...

,(SELECT d.cms__Auto_Create__c
         ,...

         ,d.cms__Content_Layout__r.cms__isPageCacheable__c

         ...
         FROM cms__ContentTemplateRelationships__r d
         ORDER BY d.cms__Content_Layout__r.cms__Name__c ASC
)
FROM cms__Content_Type__c c
WHERE c.cms__Site_Name__c = 'IXPortal'
ORDER BY c.cms__Name__c ASC
```